# Expected value of a piecewise function in two variables

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let X and Y to be two independent random variables with equal pdfs (pdfs are known). Does anyone know how to estimate the expected value of the following function???

\begin{equation}
 g(X,Y) = \biggl\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    x & \mbox{if $y<x$}, \\
    x + (y-x)^b & \mbox{if $x \le y$}. 
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
Where $b$ is a constant between 0 and 1. Important to know that x and y also range between 0 and 1.

All I have done so far is to apply definitions:

\begin{equation}
E(g(X,Y)) = \int_0^1 \int_x^1 xf_{xy}(x,y)dydx + \int_0^1 \int_y^1 (x+(y-x)^b)f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}

but I think it is simpler to apply:
\begin{equation}
E_{X,Y}\big[ g(X, Y)\big]= E_{X} \bigg[E_{Y}\big[g(x,y)\big]\bigg]=E_{X}\bigg[ \int_{y}f_Y(y)g(x,y)dy\bigg]
\end{equation}
Any advice is appreciated ....

Comment: You should probably try to reformat your math. It is unreadable. Also, have you done any work yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If $Z$ has density $f_Z$, then we have $E[f(Z)] = \int f_Z d\lambda$, and moreover this holds even if $Z$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d>1$. In particular for $Z=(X,Y)$ we know that $Z$ has density $f_Xf_Y$ because $X,Y$ are independent. Thus $E[g(Z)] = \int g(z) f_Z(z) dz = \int\int g(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy$.

In your case you can rewrite
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} g(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y) dx dy = \iint_{y<x} x f_X(x)f_Y(y) dxdy + \iint_{x \leq y} (x+(y-x)^b)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
$$
I would rewrite this as
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} xf_X(x)f_Y(y) dx dy + \iint_{x\leq y} (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
$$
$$
=\int_\mathbb{R}E[X]f_Y(y)dy +  \iint_{x\leq y} (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
$$
$$
= E[X]+  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y (y-x)^b f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
$$

Without more information about what $X,Y$'s distributions actually are I wouldn't say much more.

Comment: My plan is to analyze cases: when b= 0 and b =1..., this is because I'm just looking for a bound rather than to find an exact solution...Cheers